# Alternative solution for mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two `MySql` tables. One call `item` and other one is `price`.

Data of `item` table look like this:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| item_id | item_code | item_name | price |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|       1 | 02        | item A    | 10.00 |
|       2 | 03        | item B    | 20.00 |
|       3 | 04        | item C    | 30.00 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

Structure of Price table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
  `price_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `valid_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `valid_until` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`price_id`),
  KEY `fk_item_price_item1_idx` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_item_price_item1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What I really need is to take data from the `item` table and insert or update it to the `price` table.

If the price of the item table is not equal to the price of the item table according to the item_id, then the data related to that item_id in the price table should be updated. (Here the `valid_until` field is updated.) Then the new price should be inserted into this price table.

I know this can be done with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query. But I cannot use unique index or constraint for `item_id / price` fileds in the `price` table. Therefore, I will use two separate queries for update and insert as below.

```
UPDATE item i
  JOIN price p ON i.item_id = p.item_id
    AND p.price <> i.price
    AND CURDATE () BETWEEN p.valid_from AND COALESCE (p.valid_until, '9999-12-31')
SET p.valid_until = CURDATE () - INTERVAL 1 DAY

INSERT IGNORE INTO `price` (`price`,`item_id`, `valid_from`)
  SELECT DISTINCT `i`.`price`, `i`.`item_id`, CURDATE()
    FROM `item` `i`
    INNER JOIN `price` `p` ON `p`.`item_id` = `i`.`item_id`;
```

The update query works without any problems. But the insert query does not work properly. This means that even if there is the same price, a new row will be inserted.

Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried adding unique key to `item_id` in price table. But it works same as above.

Comment: To make `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` work correctly, all you need is a UNIQUE index on `item_id`. As you have noticed, putting the price in the unique index means it's not unique enough.

Comment: I was going to say that, but it looks like there could be different valid date ranges for the same item ID. Is that true?

Comment: @Barmar, yes you are absolutely right in this case.

Comment: Wait .... you're UPDATEing the item table and INSERTing into the price table. Maybe you can [edit] your question to clarify the business purpose of all this?

Comment: @O.Jones They're updating the existing rows, and inserting the rows that don't exist.

Comment: @O.Jones.. no I update price table ... `SET p.valid_until = CURDATE () - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a `SELECT` query to find the rows in `item` that aren't matched in the `UPDATE` query, and insert them.

```
INSERT INTO price (`price`,`item_id`, `valid_from`)
SELECT DISTINCT i.price, i.item_id, CURDATE()
FROM item AS i
LEFT JOIN price AS p ON i.item_id = p.item_id AND CURDATE () BETWEEN p.valid_from AND COALESCE (p.valid_until, '9999-12-31')
WHERE p.price_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks.. let me check it out

Comment: Barmar your solution is working perfectly .. Thank you so much